# Spring integration SFTP - Post Transfer processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I have successfully set up Spring with SFTP integration, and am polling an SFTP server and pulling down files.

What I would like to know, is it possible for a task to be fired on each file once it's download has completed? I don't want to go down the road of filesystem watches - is there something built into Spring SFTP for this?

Having looked at the documentation, it looks like it can be achieved with Channels.

This is what my receiver channel currently looks like:

```
<int:channel id="receiveChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to fire a customer interceptor or similar.

Edit: from the Spring docs it says this:

> It is also important to understand that SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter is a Polling Consumer and therefore you must configure a poller (either a global default or a local sub-element). Once the file has been transferred to a local directory, a Message with java.io.File as its payload type will be generated and sent to the channel identified by the channel attribute.

I'm not sure how to implement this - and can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others who come across this, the issue is that the messages are put on the received channel only when **ALL** files have been transferred. They are not handled one at a time (as I had expected). In my case I have thousands of large files on a remote SFTP server, and only after all of them downloaded were the messages sent to the receiver channel.

I'm not sure if this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to start from the beginning of [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) and determine for yourself that `channel` is the most important first class citizen in the integration.

So, you have an `<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>`, which responsibility to *poll* entities from the remote directory, turn them to the `java.io.File` (like you noticed in the RTFM) and send as a `payload` of `Message` to the configured channel. The subscriber for that channel will pick up the message and do some desired process under that `File` `payload`.

See also [Spring Integration Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp) for more information.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that in my deleted answer, and I thought it was working. However the send events are the only ones being fired, and only when I restart the application.

Comment: Please, read more docs and follow with the samples. You see events only on start just because there is no new files in the remote directory during application work. You really should do some `<service-activator>`, not `interceptor`. I'm not sure why you are finding my answer an non-sufficient to the question. We just "speak" different languages and you wish we do work for you in your application, when there is just enough to read some docs and do exercise with an appropriate sample.

Comment: Thanks Artem - I have switched to using service-activator. However, the method is still only being fired when the system restarts. From the docs I thought it would fire when the file has completed downloading - apologies I am trying to follow the docs, and not asking to have this done for me.

Comment: OK. Your system has started and, therefore, it started to download files from SFTP. As far as files are available locally they are moved to your channel to be picked up by the `<service-activator>`. Not sure where is a difference with expectation and an explanation in the docs...

Comment: Correct. If I let it run and 10 files download, the method doesnt fire, ever. But if I restart the application afterwards, the method fires 10 times (once for each file). I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior? It looks like I will have to implement a filesystem watch to achieve what I want? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That does not make sense. Looks like your app is short-living and doesn't allow some time frame for service-activator to make a round trip for local file copies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111215/discussion-between-j-doe-and-artem-bilan).